# WPF: Hiding object causes brief flash before disappearing

Tags: wpf, animation, data-binding, storyboard, datatrigger

I have a simple button style which has data trigger which binds to a bool property and if property is false it hides the button using simple fade out animation and vice-versa.

But for some unknown reason, for the first time when I perform some task which sets the bool value to false. It gives a brief flash before fading out. Upon setting it to true everything is as expected.

My style is

```
 <Style x:Key="CustomButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsButtonVisible}" Value="true">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" >
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2" To="1"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" >
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2" To="0"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        </DataTrigger>
        <Trigger Property="Opacity" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Opacity" Value="1" >
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="93"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="93"/>
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0"/>
     </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

**Note:-**
Default value of IsButtonVisible is true

Comment: does changing   `<DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2" To="0"/>` to   `<DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0" To="0"/>` eliminate the flash?

Comment: @KyleHancock No, it does not

Comment: I tested this style and everything works correctly.  Check your code other than this style.  post any more relevant code that may be missing.

Comment: I am wondering how fading in is supposed to work. Imagine that when the Button has previously been faded out, the Opacity is 0 and hence the Visibility is Collapsed (due to the Trigger). If the Button is subsequently faded in by animating the Opacity to 1, the Visibility will not become Visible until the Opacity animation has ended at a value of 1, which triggers the Visibility.

Comment: I got the same result as @KyleHancock. I'm not seeing any flash. What does your code-behind look like? I'd be willing to bet somewhere in your code the IsButtonVisible property is getting set more than once in quick succession. For instance, it might be getting set to false (triggering the fade out), then almost immediately to true (cancelling the fade out, giving you the "flash"), then back to false again (allowing the fade out to actually happen). In your IsButtonVisible setter I suggest you do a Debug.WriteLine or set a breakpoint to see what is happening there.

Comment: Just curious if you tried our suggestions or figured out the problem.

Comment: @PeterMoore I have tried your suggestion, it is correct that property set many times but the value which is being set remains the same. It should not effect the output but still I limit it by only setting the value which  is not the previous value but it does not work

Comment: @KyleHancock I know this style works fine, I have tested it on numerous test applications and I understand there is something else in play I just want a suggestion about what could go wrong there, What could make a button blink once and only for the first time

Comment: Ok. So to be clear, you're only calling the property change notifier when the value actually changes, not every time the property setter is called?

Comment: @PeterMoore Yes, I have just got some new information from a reliable source that my view is being reset upon doing this operation which refires the animation. I am not sure what it means, Do you?

Comment: I can't reproduce it either. Your xaml works fine without flicker og anything unexpected with a dummy viewmodel. Could you add the xaml-surroundings to where you use the style?

Comment: @MegaMind not sure. Maybe the DataContext of the view is getting changed? That could definitely do it.

Comment: @MegaMind Any update on if you've figured out the problem?

Comment: @KyleHancock Yes I have solve the issue with some help from the code behind (handle storyboard completed event), I'll post my solution in next few hours.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have two DataTrigger? Try this solution, maybe it solves your problem.

```
        <Style x:Key="DefaultButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" Value="true">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard FillBehavior="HoldEnd" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2"  To="1"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" >
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2"  To="0" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            </DataTrigger> 
            <Trigger Property="Opacity" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Opacity" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="93"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="93"/>
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0"/>
        </Style.Setters>
    </Style>
```

#### Edit:

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="279.716" Width="279.784"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyleTrue" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding VisibleTrue}" Value="true">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard FillBehavior="HoldEnd" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2"  To="1"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" >
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2"  To="0" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            </DataTrigger>
            <Trigger Property="Opacity" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Opacity" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="93"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="93"/>
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0"/>
        </Style.Setters>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyleFalse" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding VisibleFalse}" Value="true">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard FillBehavior="HoldEnd" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2"  To="1"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" >
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2"  To="0" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            </DataTrigger>
            <Trigger Property="Opacity" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Opacity" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="93"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="93"/>
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0"/>
        </Style.Setters>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="187,11,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_OnClick"/>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyleFalse}" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="47,66,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock_true" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="193,68,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyleTrue}" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="47,143,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock_false" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="193,145,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```

Code Behind

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Initalvalue is true;
    /// </summary>
    public bool VisibleTrue
    {
        get { return _VisibleTrue; }
        set
        {
            if (_VisibleTrue == value) return;
            _VisibleTrue = value;
            textBlock_true.Text = value ? "True" : "False";              
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("VisibleTrue"));
        }
    }
    private bool _VisibleTrue = true;



    /// <summary>
    /// Initialvalue is false
    /// </summary>
    public bool VisibleFalse
    {
        get { return _VisibleFalse; }
        set
        {
            if (_VisibleFalse == value) return;
            _VisibleFalse = value;
            textBlock_false.Text = value ? "True" : "False";
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("VisibleFalse"));
        }
    }
    private bool _VisibleFalse;


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        textBlock_true.Text = "Application started";
        textBlock_false.Text = "Application started";
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void Button_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        VisibleTrue = !VisibleTrue;
        VisibleFalse = !VisibleTrue;
    }
}
}
```

Preview

[image: Preview]

Comment: I'll post an edit with an example. But if my code does not help, you can add some more details of your code. Otherwise I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent setting your bound property `IsButtonVisible` while animation performs you could add the following to your `ViewModel`:

```
private bool _animationInProgress = false;
private readonly object _animationLock = new object();
private bool _isButtonVisible = true;

public bool IsButtonVisible {
    get { return _isButtonVisible; }
    set {
        lock (_animationLock) {
            if (value == _isButtonVisible || _animationInProgress) return;
            _animationInProgress = true;
        }
        _isButtonVisible = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
        Timer animationDoneTimer = new Timer {Interval = 200, Enabled = true, AutoReset = false};
        animationDoneTimer.Elapsed += (sender, args) => {
                                          lock (_animationLock) {
                                              _animationInProgress = false;
                                          }
                                      };

    }
}
```

As second thing I would remove the `Trigger`:

```
<Trigger Property="Opacity" Value="1" >
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
</Trigger>
```

For the behaviour, that you'd like to set `Visibility` to `Collapsed` on `Opacity` == 0 and `Visibility` to `Visible` on `Opacity` =! 0 you should do it this way:

```
    ...
        <Trigger Property="Opacity" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </Trigger>
        <!-- Trigger removed -->
    </Style.Triggers>
    <Style.Setters>
        <!-- Visibilities value if Trigger Opacity == 0 does not fire  -->
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />

        <Setter Property="Height" Value="93"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="93"/>
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0"/>
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```